# How I can change the default size of the ChoiceBox?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-8

I am using ChoiceBox and put the ChoiceBox into a HBox and that HBox goes to a pane. However, I notice that the default width of the choiceBox is so short. Is anyone know how I can change it? (not changing the draw down width, I would like to change the place where I would click)

[image: a screenshot of the code]

[image: a screenshot of the run case]

Comment: post the code instead of SS

Comment: Simply set the `prefWidth` property of the `ChoiceBox` as: `CDorLE.setPrefWidth(200);`.

Comment: Use javafx css  style as `-fx-pref-width: 100;`

Comment: paste the code as text into your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are methods inherited from class javafx.scene.layout.Region. You can use them if you want setMaxHeight, setMaxWidth, setMaxSize, setPrefHeight, setPrefWidth, setPrefSize.

Resource: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ChoiceBox.html#valueProperty--